# Ubuntu 15.10 get stuck at shutdown, only flashing cursor

Tags: 15.10, shutdown

My set up:

Dual boot: Ubuntu 15.10 + Windows 10 latest (not wubi)

Specs:

- i7 870 @ 2.93 gHz * 4
- DDR3 8GB ram
- 1TB HDD

Whenever i shutdown, it just stuck at flashing cursor on the top left hand corner. Any help?

Comment: Please restart and share your syslogs, dmesg and kernel logs.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Linux. How can I share the logs?

Comment: /var/log directory has the logs

Comment: But it's too long....